# Animación hover de Linear Gradient se repite

Tags: html

Estoy creando un efecto tipo *shine* o *glow* sobre un texto, la animación se activa al hacer *hover* con el cursor encima del texto y se desactiva al quitarlo.

La animación es una mascara de color gradiante y transparencia que corre de izquierda a derecha 1 sola vez dándole ese efecto de resplandor.
Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema surge que después de este efecto, se carga 1 vez más el mismo efecto pero más lento (dejando el cursor encima claro está) y solo llega hasta la mitad del texto. Quiero eliminar ese segundo efecto incompleto.

Ya intenté quitando el *infinite* para que no se crearan *loops* pero aun asi persiste. La duración del efecto es mínima *.5s*

Creo que el problema está en el *linear gradient*, pero no conozco mucho su uso y cada vez que lo modifico se daña el efecto.

Les dejo el código por si ven algo que no cuadra,

PD: Aumenté la duración del efecto a 5s para que lo noten mas claramente.

Muchas gracias!

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400);

body {
  background-color:#000;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

h1 a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

      .effect-shine:hover  {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 40%, #000 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.9) 70%); /*define la transparencia*/
  -webkit-mask-size: 200%;
  animation: shine 5s ; /*define la velocidad en segundos*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  from {
    -webkit-mask-position: 150%;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-mask-position: -50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <h1 align="center"><a class="effect-shine">EFECTO SHINE</a></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambié los valores del `-webkit-mask-position`:

```
-webkit-mask-position: 150%;
-webkit-mask-position: -50%;
```

a

```
-webkit-mask-position: 200%;
-webkit-mask-position: 0%;
```

y parecen funcionar bien ahora:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400);

body {
  background-color:#000;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

h1 a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.effect-shine:hover  {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 40%, #000 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.9) 70%); /*define la transparencia*/
  -webkit-mask-size: 200%;
  animation: shine 5s ; /*define la velocidad en segundos*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  from {
    -webkit-mask-position: 200%;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-mask-position: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <h1 align="center"><a class="effect-shine">EFECTO SHINE</a></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba, mil gracias por tomarte el tiempo Rene